# Programatically log in user in Joomla after creation

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating an application where an email is retrieved through a POST variable and a user is automatically created with a random password and everything. I got that part down. However after the user is created, how do I log the user in. As in, I assume I have to create a session right?

How would I go about doing this?

And I know how unsafe this is, but it is what the client wants.

I found the solution:
[How to log into joomla through an external script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075335/how-to-log-into-joomla-through-an-external-script)

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, but i'll try to figure out how it's coded

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution

Comment: Would you like sharing your solution with us?

Comment: Solution is in answer (for those that don't read long texts)